# Flickr Authentication inside Colorbox?

Tags: jquery, colorbox, flickr

I know that flickr cannot be authenticated inside an iframe, however I am wondering if it is possible to create a popup colorbox (or another javascript popup) to authenticate.

I need to be able to authenticate for flickr from a colorbox or popup. But turning off iframe for a colorbox doesn't work. Is there any other method anyone can think of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a pop-up window which closes on the completion of the authentication.

If you are unable to use iFrames to authenticate, then any form on in-page inclusion is not going to work, therefore the authentication page has to be opened in a separate browser window.

Comment: How could I create a popup window that closes on completion of the authentication?

Comment: I am unfamiliar with the Flickr authentication system. This would be something to look through their developer documentation for. You could create the link to the page open in a new window, with a set-size using JavaScript then if there is an option in the Flickr auth process for what page to direct to after the auth is complete, create a page which uses JavaScript to close the window.